# Fallback interpreter for shell script?

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm trying to launch a node program as a shell script. Example

```
#!/usr/bin/node

console.log('hello')
```

Problem is in some environement the node bin is at `/usr/bin/node` and in some it's at `/usr/local/bin/node`

I'd like to fix this problem without a symlink or something like that. I'm open to having multiple shell scripts or something but I don't want to have to configure the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why `env` exists. It always belongs in `/usr/bin`, and it checks your whole `PATH` for what you really want to run. Use `#!/usr/bin/env node` instead.